# Failed to assign topic to null. Please ensure you have permissions to assign topics for this record.: [EntityId]

Tags: code-coverage

Iam getting below error after running test class:

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD
, Failed to assign topic to null. Please ensure you have permissions to assign topics for this record.: [EntityId]

```
         public with sharing class S360_PostTopicMention {
//@InvocableMethod(label='Post Topic' description='Returns the list of account names corresponding to the specified account IDs.')
public static void postTopicToChatter(List<ID> ids) {

    List<TopicAssignment> listTopic = [SELECT EntityId,Topic.Id,Topic.Name FROM TopicAssignment WHERE EntityId in :ids];

    for(TopicAssignment l: listTopic){
        //ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), l.id, ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, 'Post');
        postWithMention(l);
    }

}


Public static void postWithMention(TopicAssignment topicAssignment){
    ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
    //ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
    ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
    ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

    messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

    //mentionSegmentInput.id = topicAssignment.EntityId;
    //messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);

    textSegmentInput.text = 'Topic #[' + topicAssignment.Topic.Name  + ']';
    messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

    feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
    feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
    feedItemInput.subjectId = topicAssignment.EntityId;

    ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput);
```

}

### }

Test class:

```
      @isTest
     public class S360_PostTopicMention_Test {
public static testmethod void testPostTopicMention(){


    user u=S360_UtilityTestClass.createUser();
    insert u;

    List<contact> contacts=new List<contact>();
    for(integer i=0;i<=10;i++){
        contact c=new contact();
        c.lastname='test'+i;
        contacts.add(c);
    }
    List<id> clist=new List<id>();
    for(contact c:contacts){
        clist.add(c.Id);
    }




    Topic newTopic = new Topic(Name='newArticleTopic', NetworkId='0DB24000000TNlXGAW');
    insert newTopic;
    system.debug('newTopic@@'+newTopic.Id);

    Topic newTopic2 = [select Id from Topic where Id=:newTopic.Id];

    system.debug('****'+newTopic2.Id);

    TopicAssignment newTopicAssignment = new TopicAssignment(TopicId=newTopic2.Id, NetworkId='0DB24000000TNlXGAW');
    insert newTopicAssignment;

    system.debug('******'+newTopicAssignment.Id);

    TopicAssignment TopicAssign = [SELECT EntityId,Topic.Id,Topic.Name FROM TopicAssignment WHERE Id =:newTopicAssignment.id LIMIT 1];
    system.debug(TopicAssign.EntityId);
    S360_PostTopicMention.postTopicToChatter(clist);
     S360_PostTopicMention.postWithMention(TopicAssign);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting This error because in your actual flow you are calling the `TopicAssignment` with `Topic.Name` field.

While in your test class you are directly passing a new instance. When we create a new instance we can't access parent fields without querying them.

So add this query in your test class and pass the new instance.

```
TopicAssignment TopicAssign = [SELECT EntityId,Topic.Id,Topic.Name FROM TopicAssignment WHERE Id =: newTopicAssignment.id LIMIT 1];
S360_PostTopicMention.postWithMention(TopicAssign);
```

Comment: I have done same thing.still iam getting below error:Failed to assign topic to null. Please ensure you have permissions to assign topics for this record.System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Failed to assign topic to null. Please ensure you have permissions to assign topics for this record.: [EntityId]

Comment: I have updated my post please check  it..